# JavaScript: filter the table using particular column

Tags: javascript

Here this is my js. I need to filter a table using this. It works correctly but. When the control come out of function the table came back to normal form without filter, i make sure this by the help of alert() in end of function.. when alert shows the table seams to be clearly sorted. when it get out of function table come back to its normal data

```
function search (tableid)
      {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableid).tBodies[0];


        var mt = (document.getElementById("srchMsgType").value).trim().toLowerCase();

        var ele;


        for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++)
        {


            ele = table.rows[r].cells[4].innerHTML.trim();



            if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(mt)==0 )
                {

                table.rows[r].style.display = '';


                }
            else 
                {
                    table.rows[r].style.display = 'none';
                }
        }
        alert();
      }
```

for eg expected output is

```
when i/p is 8
no mt
1  8
2  8
4  8

During alert messgae display time it works as if the above expected answer.asfter clicking ok to it


answer  is
no mt
1  8
2  8
3  10
4  8
5  25
```

Comment: Do you really want to get your hands dirty with DOM manipulation yourself? Why not use a data binding library like KnockoutJS or AngularJS, create an array of objects, bind them to the table and simply filter the array instead of this?

Comment: You filter code works fine. You probably have more code and need to look into it. Here : https://jsfiddle.net/hy7vtqtu/